# How to delay loading iframe in a jquery collapsed div until after clicking the div/button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, delay

Basically, I have a whole lot of these collapsing divs on one page, which have iframes inside the collapsed div. (I used css to make the clickable div look like a button.)

The problem is that it's taking a very long time for the page to load, because basically it's loading every single domain in each iframe every time the page loads.

I want to delay loading any of the iframes unless the div is clicked.

Here is my code currently:

**the Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".cont").hide();
  jQuery(".title").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".cont").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

**the HTML**

```
<div class="layer1">
<p class="title">test</p>
    <div class="cont">
        <iframe src="http://example.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <iframe src="http://example2.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <iframe src="http://example3etc.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
```

still need a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about only inserting it into the DOM after the button is clicked?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("cont1").click(function()
         {
            $("cont1").html("<iframe src='http://example1.com' scrolling="no"></iframe>")
          }
    );

    $("cont2").click(function()
         {
            $("cont2").html("<iframe src='http://example2.com' scrolling="no"></iframe>")
         }
     );

});
```

And so on.  And you could use a "remove" button to remove the html afterwards?

Comment: Well, I can't use inline javascript (it's within the Google Chrome extension popup and only runs javascript from a file, and will not run inline javascript). What is a workaround? It seems like a good solution, just we need to use it for my needs. I will accept if you can get it working not inline.

Comment: what do you mean "not inline"?  i edited it so it's wrapped in a "document ready", so it should work the same way that the code you presented worked, right?

Comment: I see, you want me to add the class cont1 and cont2 etc, and put that javascript into the javascript file. But also I need to as well use the same button to click again to remove. I didn't realize that with your code there is no way to remove.

Comment: still need a solution.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9Fw5D/118/.  this is a basic hide/show example you could modify to work with whatever you're using it for.  the same button adds and removes.